# How come a current sheet of $J_s = J_0 \hat{x}$ produces plane wave solution?

Tags: boundary-conditions, microwaves

Given in the picture. There is a current sheet $J_s = J_0 \hat{x}$. Supposedly Jo is not oscillating. So, how does this thing create a plane waves propagating away from the current sheet? Shouldn't there be an oscillating source to create waves in the medium?

I've added a corresponding image.

[image: It is from, Microwave Engineering by David M. Pozar]

Comment: I fixed up the TeX formatting. Please look at the source of the post (hit the edit button) to see how it's done. Good formatting helps people read your question and makes it more likely that you'll get an answer.

Comment: But the Fourier transform of constant is an impulse at $\omega=0$. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The $J$ in the question is not a constant. It is a phasor. It has an inherent $e^{jwt}$ with it. In the book, phasor form is used in these aspects.

[Found an answer after researching a bit. Now it seems was really an easy concept...]